# Scala.JS + Spray in multi project with SBT

Tags: scala, sbt, spray, scala.js

I'm trying to have a clean setup of SBT for a multi project, the client in Scala.JS and the other for the server in Spray.
I have been able to hook the generation of the JS in fastOptJS for run and fullOptJS for runProd.
What I'm not able is to set the `resources`

```
lazy val root = project.in(file(".")).aggregate(client, server)

lazy val client = project.in(file("client"))

lazy val server = project.in(file("server"))

run := (run in(server, Compile)).evaluated

// run for dev mode
run <<= run dependsOn (fastOptJS in(client, Compile))

// The hook that doesn't work
(resources in(server, Compile, run)) ++= Seq(
  (artifactPath in(client, Compile, fastOptJS)).value,
  (artifactPath in(client, Compile, packageJSDependencies)).value,
  (artifactPath in(client, Compile, packageScalaJSLauncher)).value
)

// runProd for prod mode
lazy val runProd = inputKey[Unit]("Run in production")

runProd := (run in(server, Compile)).evaluated

runProd <<= runProd dependsOn (fullOptJS in(client, Compile))

// The hook that doesn't work
(resources in(server, Compile, runProd)) ++= Seq(
  (artifactPath in(client, Compile, fullOptJS)).value,
  (artifactPath in(client, Compile, packageJSDependencies)).value,
  (artifactPath in(client, Compile, packageScalaJSLauncher)).value
)
```

But when I use the spray-resolver's command `re-start` for the same trick that's working:

```
reStart <<= (reStart in(server, Compile)) dependsOn (fastOptJS in(client, Compile))

(resources in(server, Compile, reStart)) ++= Seq(
  (artifactPath in(client, Compile, fastOptJS)).value,
  (artifactPath in(client, Compile, packageJSDependencies)).value,
  (artifactPath in(client, Compile, packageScalaJSLauncher)).value
)
```

So do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know so much about Spray, so I am unsure what `resources` really impacts, but I doubt it does what you want. You probably need to copy the .js files to one of the resources directory used by Spray instead?

Comment: You mean Spray right?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I edited my comment.

Comment: No problem. I took this idea, of just adding the path to the generated JS in the other project and not copying them, from Li Haoyi [here](https://github.com/lihaoyi/workbench-example-app/blob/autowire/build.sbt)

Comment: Try and remove the `, runProd` part. It might be the case that `runProd` doesn't look for `resources` scoped to its task, but rather in the Global task within the `Compile` configuration.